# How to deploy client webpack bundle to production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, digital-ocean, webpack-dev-server

I'm currently deploying an app to my digital ocean nodejs environment, it's a client-only bundle, talking to APIs. I've been using devserver for development so far, but I'm guessing this is not intended to be used for production, since my bundle is huge (1.8 MB).

This is my devserver setup:

```
var
    WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    config = require('./webpack.config');

const compiler = webpack(config);
const server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    compress: true,
    inline: true,
    hot: true
});

server.listen(8000);
```

My webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
  },
  devServer: {
      historyApiFallback:{
          index:'/index.html'
      },
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file',
        query: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'wc-loader'
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map'
};
```

**I'm now trying to reduce the bundle, I think I need to stop using devserver for that? What I have so far (with devserver but different config):**

```
var
WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server'),
webpack = require('webpack'),
config = require('./production_webpack.config');

const compiler = webpack(config);
const server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    compress: true,
    inline: true,
    hot: true
});

server.listen(8000);
```

My production config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map'
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['node_modules'],
  },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: false
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      beautify: false,
      mangle: {
        screw_ie8: true,
        keep_fnames: true
      },
      compress: {
        screw_ie8: true
      },
      comments: false
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file',
        query: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'wc-loader'
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Comment: For sure you should drop using webpack-dev-server for your prod build. You should take artifacts generated by webpack prod build and use for example express.js for creating standalone server for serving your application.

Comment: Do you have have any project/library dependencies?

You can split your `bundle.js` if that imports dependencies by adding a `vendor.bundle` with `CommonChunksPlugin` - or using cdn scripts of those dependencies -